# How do I remove the title bar only for one Activity?

Tags: android

How to get one single ACTIVITY without Title?

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

This code is in styles.xml ! when i am using "NoActionBar" then all activity show no title bar,

Answer (score 0):

Apply the theme without an `ActionBar` only for the specific `Activity` that requires it. It has to be set in the `manifest.xml` in the `Activity` tag: `android:theme="@style/<YourAppThemeWithoutActionbarHere>"`

Answer (score 0):

You can define one another **style** into your **styles.xml** , where you can use **NoActionBar** in **Theme**.

```
<style name="AppThemeWithoutActionBar" 
    parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

and then go to your project's **Manifest file** , and then
you can apply this new style (without an ActionBar) only for the specific Activity that requires it.

```
<activity 
     android:name=".YourActivityWhereYouDoNotWantToolbar"
     android:theme="@style/AppThemeWithoutActionBar">
```

It will solve your problem.